# как будет верно? по JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Все официанты любят чаевые и даже оценивают их согласно секретному рейтингу!

Реализуй функцию getTipsRating, которая принимает сумму чаевых amount и возвращает строку-оценку в зависимости от оставленной суммы:

```
terrible, если amount равна 0 грн;
poor, если amount от 1 до 10 грн включительно;
good, если amount от 11 до 20 грн включительно;
great, если amount от 21 до 50 грн включительно;
excellent, если amount больше 50 грн.
```

Вот мой код неверный ошибку выдает

> Function 'getTipsRating' should return 'terrible' for 0 tips amount!!!!

Сам код:

```
function getTipsRating(amount) {
    if (amount == 0) {
        return "terible";
    } else if (1 <= amount && amount <= 10) {
        return "poor";
    } else if (11 <= amount && amount <= 20) {
        return "good";
    } else if (21 <= amount && amount <= 50) {
        return "great";
    } else {
        return "excellent";
    }
}
```

Comment: `terrible` != `terible`

Comment: Более того `terrible` !== `terible`

Comment: Ну и писать в вопросе функцию в одну строку это издевательство над читателями.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Прям многострочный с рандомными отступами - не издевательство

Comment: @EzioMercer да есть же банальные форматтеры онлайн.... тот же https://jsonformatter.org/jsbeautifier  или https://codebeautify.org/jsviewer

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да можно хоть во встроенном Фрагменте кода, сделать)) Но кто это делает?) Я после того как получил права править без согласования, уже перестал просить об этом, просто форматирую, когда бывает охота))

Answer (score 3):

```js
function getTipsRating(amount) {
  return ["terrible", "poor", "good", "great", "excellent"][(amount>0) + (amount>10) + (amount>20) + (amount>50)]
}

for (let amount of [0, 1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 20, 21, 25, 49, 50, 51, 1000]) {
  console.log(amount, getTipsRating(amount))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: Интересно это будет быстрее на больших данных или `switch case`? 

Comment: Я сразу не въехал, что происходит, но это круто!

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Преборазования `true` в `1` и `false` в `0`)

Comment: @EzioMercer, при том, что я массив создаю прям в функции, вероятно, будет медленнее. Если сделать константу с массивом снаружи, то будет лучше, но всё равно медленнее, потому что надо посчитать все условия для суммы, а switch остановится на первом. Можно похимичить с оптимизацией и получить то же самое, но вряд ли есть смысл.

Comment: @EzioMercer, ыцшеср всегда работает до первого. `switch (undefined) { case console.log(1): console.log(10); break; case console.log(2): console.log(20); }` - будет 1 и 10.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137954/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy-----javascript).