# Как добавить класс аккордиону после ajax запроса?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajax-load

У меня есть 5 аккордионов, в каждом аккордионе лежат свои ссылке, по нажатию на аккордион показывается ссылки внутри него, нажимая на ссылку идет ajax запрос. Каким образом мне после ajax запроса присвоить класс данному аккордиону ?

```
<div class="filter_wrap filter_floor2">
<h3 class="title_lable_filter">Коммуникации<span></span></h3>
<div class="filter_wrap_chek">
    <div class="filter_option_list">
        <div class="filter_group">
            <a href="#" class=" label_filter"> Газ</a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="filter_group">
            <a href="#" class=" label_filter"> Интернет</a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="filter_group">
            <a href="#" class=" label_filter"> Электричество</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$.get(url, function(res) {
$content.replaceWith($(res).find('#content_wrap'));
InitFilterTab();
FiletrOpenClose();
$('#card_wrapper').removeClass('ajax-on');
$('body').removeClass('hidden');
```

}, 'html')

Comment: Вам этот метод нужен `xhr.onload` ?

Comment: @EzioMercer а может success а может complete, а может then. Автор тайный агент и своего кода не показывает))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну и не поспоришь) Помечаем как нужно уточнить?)

Comment: Здравствуйте, код не секретный

Comment: Подскажите что именно нужно выложить ajax ? или верстку ?

Comment: А можно в минимальном виде оба?)

Comment: Добавил)
<script>
$.get(
    url,
    function(res){
    $content.replaceWith($(res).find('#content_wrap'));
    InitFilterTab();
    FiletrOpenClose();
     $('#card_wrapper').removeClass('ajax-on');
     $('body').removeClass('hidden');
}, 'html')
</script>

Comment: Не в комментарии пожалуйста. Скрипт тоже в вопрос добавьте

Comment: А можно пожалуйста не в 1 строку? Посмотрите на эти онлайн сервисы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1431413/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be-javascript/1431419?noredirect=1#comment2552244_1431413

Comment: Спасибо, отформатировал)

Comment: Вот тут есть все способы того что вам надо https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Честно говоря, я гуглил данный вопрос перед тем как задать его, это тоже видел, но не особо понимаю как это мне поможет вычислить элемент с которым я взаимоджействовал и присвоить ему класс, именно ему, а не всем аккордионам на странице после ajax запроса